# Pylance in VSCode still shows reportMissingImports even after editing python.analysis.extraPaths

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have been breaking my head trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Hope someone can help me with this. I have a folder in my current working directory in Visual Studio Code 1.69.2 on a Ubuntu 22.04 system with miniconda environments. The folder has some python scripts with functions and classes that I want to use in a jupyter notebook in vscode. I also named the folder in which I have additional python scripts as **src**. This is what the directory structure looks like.

[image: File Structure]

I have the python.analysis.autoSearchPaths to True. So, in principle, the python files in src should be detected automatically. However, PyLance still shows the reportMissingImports error. However, I am able to access the functions and classes in that folder.  Additionally, I have also added that path to the python.analysis.extraPaths in the settings

[image: Settings File]

However, I still get the Pylance error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

[image: File Error]

I will be really grateful if someone could help me out here. Cheers

### Edit 1

I have attached screenshots of the exact error being shown
[image]

And the problem seems to be exclusively with the Jupyter extension in vscode and Pylance is working as expected in a .py file

Comment: Maybe the names should be different? instead of "srs.Optics as Optics", what if you try "src.Optics as OpticsLib"?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, when I tried it out, it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I created the same file structure as you, but everything [works fine on my machine](https://imgur.com/a/AjOwodK). Even if I restore all the settings, there is still no error in vscode without any settings. Please hover over the yellow squiggly line and tell us the detailed error message. And which theme are you using?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and replicate the error. It's very strange that it is not reproducible in your case. I have this error only in Jupyter notebooks and not in a regular .py file. So I am not sure if something's broken in Pylance or in Jupyter extension. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling vscode and also all the packages. I am using the Dark+ theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong. There seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3017) with LSP Notebooks experiment on vscode that affects Jupyter Notebooks in the editor. The solution seems to be to set the "python.pylanceLspNotebooksEnabled" flag to False which by default is set to True and it fixes the problem of this error in Jupyter Notebooks in vscode.

[image]

[image]

This problem only seems to affect the docstring but doesn't affect autocomplete. Thanks to others who tried to help with this question and hope it helps those who might come across the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the error report of the **Yellow wavy** line.

> PyLance still shows the reportMissingImports error. However, I am able to access the functions and classes in that folder. Additionally

I think the error content of the Yellow wavy line should be **reportunusedimport**.

[image]

You can change the following code in your **setting.json**:

```
  "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportUnusedImport": "none",
  },
```

In this way, you will not be warned of unused imports：

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get the reportMissingimports and not the reportUnusedImport. I am using functions in both of those imports in the rest of my code. I have edited my original answer to include those screenshots

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in `pyproject.toml` file with `extraPaths` option specified. It seems to have precedence over the `python.analysis.extraPaths` setting in vs code.